# MySQL JOIN to pull up latest posts by comparing post dates and comments dates

Tags: mysql, group-by

Well, I have two tables community and community_comments.
community is the table where the topic title and other details of the topic is stored.
community_details is the table in which all the posts or comments for the topic/thread is stored.

I need to pull up the latest five topics based on the comments date for threads as well as date of the original topic/thread.

Now there maybe some threads which do not have any comments yet, but are more recent than some threads which do have comments. I need to pull them up correctly.

I tried queries such as

```
SELECT MAX(community_comments.id), `community`.*
FROM (`community`)
LEFT JOIN `community_comments` ON `community`.`id`=`community_comments`.`community_id`
WHERE `community`.`type` = 1
GROUP BY `community_comments`.`id`
ORDER BY `community_comments`.`date_posted` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

this pulls up the same thread multiple times, and this

```
SELECT MAX(community_comments.id), `community`.*
FROM (`community`)
LEFT JOIN `community_comments` ON `community`.`id`=`community_comments`.`community_id`
WHERE `community`.`type` = 1
GROUP BY `community_comments`.`community_id`
ORDER BY `community_comments`.`date_posted` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

pulls up unique threads but doesnt pull up the correct latest ones.

The table structure for community is :

```
CREATE TABLE `community` (   
  `id` varchar(12) character set utf8 NOT NULL,   
  `title` varchar(255) character set utf8 NOT NULL,   
  `content` text character set utf8 NOT NULL,   
  `author` varchar(13) character set utf8 NOT NULL,   
  `category` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,   
  `type` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1' COMMENT '1 = Forum; 2 = Site Help; 3 = Local & Global',   
  `location` varchar(100) character set utf8 NOT NULL,   
  `country` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,   
  `date_posted` datetime NOT NULL,   
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)   
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

and table structure for community_comments is :

```
CREATE TABLE `community_comments` (   
  `id` varchar(12) character set utf8 NOT NULL,   
  `community_id` varchar(12) character set utf8 NOT NULL,   
  `content` text character set utf8 NOT NULL,   
  `member_id` varchar(13) character set utf8 NOT NULL,   
  `type` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1' COMMENT '1 = Forum; 2 = Site Help; 3 =  Local & Global',   
  `quoted` varchar(12) character set utf8 NOT NULL COMMENT 'Id number of the comment that is being quoted',   
  `date_posted` datetime NOT NULL,   
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)   
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In your first query, wouldn't you want to be grouping by the community id instead of the community comment id?

Comment: @MrSlayer Yep, I tried that too but it gave inaccurate results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I'm understanding correctly, you need the community fields that have the 5 most recent community_comments on them.  You want to use the SQL Group By to get this right.

```
SELECT c.*, MAX(com.date_posted) as last_post
FROM community c
LEFT OUTER JOIN community_comments com
ON com.community_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY MAX(com.date_posted) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

If you don't want to show communities that have no comments, you can replace the left outer join with an inner join.

Comment: McKevin, thanks for the answer, I tried it out. It works perfectly if all threads have posts in the community_comments table. It does pull up the records correctly when there are some threads with no posts, but the ordering goes wrong. Looking into it now.

Comment: How do you differentiate between threads and posts? Are they both held in your community_comments table?  Or are the communities the threads?  I've tried the query locally based on your table structure and if a community doesn't have a related community_comment, it gets sorted last in the list.  How would you want it to behave?

Comment: For threads that didn't have comments, the last_post was NULL, Add a IFNULL clause did the job :)

Comment: Community table holds the threads. When a new thread is created, the details are inserted in the community table. There is no record for the new thread in the community_comments table. When somebody posts in the thread, it is stored in the community_comments table. So for each thread, the thread details is stored in the community table, and the posts for the thread in the community_comments table.

Comment: Cool, then yes your solution of using an IFNULL or COALESCE would be the best way of falling back to the community table's date posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.*, IFNULL(MAX(com.date_posted),c.date_posted) as last_post 
            FROM community c 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN community_comments com 
            ON com.community_id = c.id 
            GROUP BY c.id 
            ORDER BY last_post DESC 
            LIMIT 5 ;
```